# Determine values for constants a and b to make the following CDF valid

Tags: probability

Find values for constants a and b such that the following cdf is valid

$$\hspace{10mm} F(x) =  \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 
1-ae^{-x/b} & &  x \geq 0 \\
0  & & otherwise  \end{array}\right\}
$$

I first find the pdf by taking the derivative of the cdf and it results in

$$ f(x)= \frac{a}{b}e^{-x/b}$$

apply the property where 
$$\int_{0}^{ \infty} f(x) =1$$

I get the value for a is equal to 1; this is where I am stuck, any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, proving that $F$ is a cdf is equivalent to prove that its derivative $f$ is a pdf, and you had already it...

But it is often simpler to remain at the level of $F$, conceptually and practically.

We assume in the sequel that $a$ and $b$ are $>0$.

Let us recall the necessary and sufficient conditions for a function $F$ to be a cdf : It must be

- 1) ascending (it is the case here, because it is the sum of an ascending function $-ae^{-x/b}$ and a constant),
- 2) such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)=1$ (this is the case here),
- 3) and such that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x)=0$, [in fact, replaced by :  $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)=0$ because $X$ is positive random variable]. It provides the the unique constraint : $1-ae^{b0}=0$, i.e., $1-a=0$, i.e.,

> $a=1$ ; $b$ is not ''hampered'': hence, it can take any $>0$ value.